# Fixing this linkedlist, not displaying the expected output

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I thought I had everything right but when I compile the program the output is not what I was expecting. I wanted the program to display "0 1 2 3 4 5" but to no avail. I did be grateful if someone can help point out my mistake or fix the program. Thks

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Item {
    int val;
    Item* next;
};

void insert(Item *head, int value) {
    Item *newnode = new Item;
    newnode->val =value;
    newnode->next = nullptr;

    if (!head) {
        head=newnode;
    }
    else {
        Item *temp = head;

        while (temp->next != nullptr)
            temp=temp->next;

        temp->next = newnode;

    }
}

void display(Item *head) {
    Item *temp = head;

    while (temp) {
        cout << temp->val << " " << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Item *head1=nullptr;

    for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        insert(head1,k);

    display(head1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not compiling or not running (crashing)?

Comment: `while (temp->next != nullptr)` -> `while (temp != nullptr)` in `display` (or just `while (temp)` will do).

Comment: Also, you can factor out `newnode->next = nullptr;` in `insert`.

Comment: Look at `head1` after the insertion loop and you will see that it is still the null pointer. Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: `void insert(Item *head...` -> `void insert(Item *&head...` If you make `head` a reference to a pointer you can change it inside the function. https://godbolt.org/z/1sTK7j4Kb

Comment: The way I'd fix the program is to use **C++**’s own `std::list`, which has been thoroughly debugged, for the linked list.

Comment: @Eljay So True. However it seems a lot of people have datastructure classes *using* C++. They are not actually learning C++ itself. And I regret that because they learn that "C++" is hard instead of "C++" is fun.

Comment: Hey John, maybe you can ask you teacher that after you've done your assignments he can teach you about the build in std::list from #include <list> and tell your fellow students that is what they should use from now on. I am curious about your teachers response.

Comment: Thanks, guys; I finally got the solution. However, I thought since I am passing a pointer to the insert function, it's passing the address of the head1 pointer to the insert function, and I don't have to pass by value any longer; why dId I have to pass by reference again

Comment: @wisejohn You're passing the *value* of `head1` to the function. That value happens to be an address, but it's not the address of `head1`.

Comment: Obligatory [Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) as C++, by Kate Gregory, CppCon 2015.  As Pepijn said, it makes people think "C++ is hard" rather than "C++ is fun".

Comment: On a (very) side note, I sometimes wonder how many aspiring chefs hear the advice "you don't need to cook it if you can buy it", or musicians "don't play that piece, there are lots of great recordings already". The point of implementing a linked list is not that it is a linked list, but that it's the simplest possible (reasonably) useful linked data structure and serves as a decent introduction to pointers (and, in the best cases, an introduction to implementation tradeoffs and sentinel values and such things).

Comment: @wisejohn many people got confused by passing by value/reference/pointer; take a look at this short example: https://godbolt.org/z/7s5WrGMb1

Answer (score 1):

Your insert method takes a `Item *` by value so it can not alter the `head` variable in the main function. So you are calling insert with `nullptr` over and over and never changing `head`. If you pass by reference instead the code works:

```
void insert(Item *&head, int value) {
    ...
}
```

But it's not very C++-ish. C++ has constructors and destructors, use them. Your code leaks memory because you never free the list. It's worth it to capsulate functionality in a container `List` instead of using the `Item*` directly. And if you keep track of the tail of the list then inserting at the end becomes much faster, which a `List` container allows you to do easily:

```
#include <iostream>

class List {
    struct Node {
        Node(Node **&tail, int val_) : val(val_) {
            *tail = this;
            tail = &this->next;
        }
        int val;
        Node* next{nullptr};
    };

public:
    ~List() {
        clear();
    }

    void clear() {
        while (head) {
            Node *temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        tail = &head;
    }

    void insert(int value) {
        new Node(tail, value);
    }

    std::ostream & print(std::ostream &out) const {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp) {
            out << temp->val << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        return out;
    }
private:
    Node *head{nullptr};
    Node **tail{&head};
};

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &out, const List &list) {
    return list.print(out);
}

int main()
{
    List list;

    for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        list.insert(k);

    std::cout << list << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```